# Find a tight upper bound on complexity of the below program:

Tags: c, time-complexity, big-o

Find a tight upper bound on the complexity of this program.

I tried. I think the time complexity of this code O(n<sup>2</sup>).

```
void function(int n) 
{ 
    int count = 0; 
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
        for (int j=i; j< i*i; j++) 
            if (j%i == 0) 
            { 
                for (int k=0; k<j; k++) 
                    printf("*"); 
            } 
}
```

But the answer given is O(n<sup>5</sup>). How?

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you get this question from? Someone asked the same question, with the same incorrect bound of O(n^5), a few years back. Is this from a textbook, a set of online notes, or something else?

Answer (score 3):

***EDIT:*** Yikes, after spending the time to answer this question, I discovered that this is a duplicate of a previous question that I had also answered three years ago. Oops!

---

The tightest bound you can get on this function's runtime is **Θ(n<sup>4</sup>)**. Here's the derivation.

This is a great place to illustrate a great general strategy for determining the big-O of a piece of code:

> "When in doubt, work inside out!"

Let's take your code:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    for (int j=i; j< i*i; j++) 
    {
        if (j%i == 0) 
        { 
            for (int k=0; k<j; k++) 
            {
                printf("*"); 
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Our approach for analyzing the runtime complexity will be to repeatedly take the innermost loop and replace it with the amount of work that it does. When we're done, we'll have our final time complexity.

Let's begin with this innermost loop:

```
 for (int k=0; k<j; k++) 
 {
     printf("*"); 
 }
```

The amount of work done here is Θ(j), since the number of loop iterations is directly proportional to j and we do a constant amount of work per loop iteration. So let's replace this loop with the simpler "do Θ(j) work," giving us this simplified loop nest:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
{
    for (int j=i; j< i*i; j++) 
    {
        if (j%i == 0) 
        { 
            do Θ(j) work 
        } 
    }
}
```

Now, let's take aim at what's now the innermost loop:

```
    for (int j=i; j < i*i; j++) 
    {
        if (j%i == 0) 
        { 
            do Θ(j) work 
        } 
    }
```

This loop is unusual in that the amount of work that it does varies pretty dramatically from one iteration to the next. Specifically:

- most iterations will do only O(1) work, but
- one out of every `i` iterations will do Θ(j) work.

To analyze this loop, we'll therefore split the work apart into these two constituent pieces and see how much each contributes to the total.

First, let's look at the "easy" iterations of the loop, which do only O(1) work. There are a total of Θ(i<sup>2</sup>) iterations of the loop (the loop starts counting at j = i and stops when j = i<sup>2</sup> and i<sup>2</sup> - i = Θ(i<sup>2</sup>). We can therefore bound the contribution of the of these "easy" loop iterations at O(i<sup>2</sup>) work.

Now, what about the "hard" loop iterations? These iterations occur when j = i, when j = 2i, when j = 3i, j = 4i, etc. Moreover, each of these "hard" iterations do work directly proportional to j during the iteration. This means that, if we add up the work across all of these iterations, the total work done is given by

> i + 2i + 3i + 4i + ... + (i - 1)i.

We can simplify this as follows:

> i + 2i + 3i + 4i + ... + (i - 1)i
>
> = i(1 + 2 + 3 + ... + i-1)
>
> = i · Θ(i<sup>2</sup>)
>
> = Θ(i<sup>3</sup>).

This uses the fact that 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + k = k(k + 1) / 2 = Θ(k<sup>2</sup>), which is Gauss's famous sum.

So now we see that the work done by the inner loop here is given by

> O(i<sup>2</sup>) work for the easy iterations, and
>
> Θ(i<sup>3</sup>) work for the hard iterations.

Summing this up, we see that the total work done by this inner loop is Θ(i<sup>3</sup>). Continuing our process of working inside out, we can replace this inner loop with "do Θ(i<sup>3</sup>) work" to get the following:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
{
    do Θ(i^3) work 
}
```

From here, we see that the work done is

> 1<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>3</sup> + 3<sup>3</sup> + ... + (n - 1)<sup>3</sup>,

and that sum is Θ(n<sup>4</sup>). (Specifically, it's n<sup>2</sup>(n - 1)<sup>2</sup> / 4.)

So overall, the theory predicts that the runtime should be Θ(n<sup>4</sup>), which is a factor of n lower than the O(n<sup>5</sup>) bound you mentioned above. How does the theory match the practice?

I ran this code on a variety of values of n and counted how many times that a star was printed. Here's the values I got back:

```
n =  500: 7760510375
n = 1000: 124583708250
n = 1500: 631407093625
n = 2000: 1996668166500
n = 2500: 4876304426875
n = 3000: 10113753374750
n = 3500: 18739952510125
n = 4000: 31973339333000
n = 4500: 51219851343375
```

If the runtime is Θ(n<sup>4</sup>), then if we double the size of the input, we should scale the output by a factor of 16. If the runtime is Θ(n<sup>5</sup>), then doubling the input size should scale the output by a factor of 32. Here's what I found:

```
Ratio of n = 1000 to n = 500: 16.0535
Ratio of n = 2000 to n = 1000: 16.0267
Ratio of n = 3000 to n = 1500: 16.0178
Ratio of n = 4000 to n = 2000: 16.0133
```

This strongly suggests that the runtime of this function is indeed Θ(n<sup>4</sup>) rather than Θ(n<sup>5</sup>).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The first loop

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
```

Gives your first O(n) multiplier.

Next, the second loop

```
for (int j=i; j< i*i; j++)
```

Itself multiplies by O(n^2) complexity because `i` is "like" `n` here.

The third loop

```
for (int k=0; k<j; k++)
```

Multiplies by another O(n^2) because `j` is "like" `n^2` here.

So you get complexity O(n^5).

Comment: The inner loop is also O(n^2) because it uses the counter from the second loop as its maximum, so it is based on i*i as well. So O(n^5).

Comment: @Deepstop Thanks, I had debated between the two, I've never actually learned time complexity.

Comment: Did a simulation. Seems much closer to O(n⁴)

Comment: @klutt I ran a similar simulation and have some math to back up the O(n^4) claim.

Comment: While O(n⁵) is technically correct, it's like saying that an average person weighs less than 300kg (600lbs). It's true, but there are much better answers.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other poster, except the innermost loop is O(n^2), as `k` spans from 0 to `j`, which itself spans up to n^2. This gives us the desired answer of O(n^5).

Comment: how come it true in the first inner loop when it check conditon i=0, j=0 and condition is j<i*i which become (0<0) how it is true? again when i=1, j=1 condition is j<i*i(1<1)again how it is true? most inner loop is not even executing when i=1,2.

Comment: @HiteshJangid for 0 and 1 that's correct, but for `i = 2`, `j` begins at 2, and the condition is `j < 4`.